# Solidity events callback in nodejs

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm using ethereum to create a transaction system. My goal is to record every transaction when an event is fired and the client shall receive a response whether the transaction was successfully executed. Here's my code:

```
   app.post('/transfer', function (req, res) {
        var from = req.user.address;
        var to = req.payload.to;
        var amount = req.payload.amount;
        point.transfer.sendTransaction(from, to, amount);
        var event = point.PointTransfer({}, '', function (error, result) {
            console.log(error);
            if (!error) {
                console.log("Point transfer: " + result.args.amount + " points were sent. Balances now are as following: \n Sender:\t" + result.args.c + " \t" + wardpoint.balance.call(result.args.sender) + " tokens \n Receiver:\t" + result.args.receiver + " \t" + wardpoint.balance.call(result.args.receiver) + " points");
                var transaction = new Transaction({
                    sender: result.args.sender,
                    receiver: result.args.receiver,
                    amount: result.args.amount
                });
                transaction.save(function (err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);
                    else
                        // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of the new user
                        res.json(req.body);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way, as it appears that the event is fired at a period of time after a transaction is executed. What is the best practise to implement response withn a solidity event?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the event is happening some time after the transaction is that the event fires when the transaction is *mined*, not when it is made.

Note that even a mined transaction may not actually stay mined, because it can be in the non-canonical chain (i.e. a short-lived fork.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is best practice, but how about:

- `point.transfer.sendTransaction()` gives you the transaction hash
- you return this hash to the poster
- the poster then finds a way to asynchronously request for the transaction receipt
- the poster looks into `receipt.logs`

Comment: is it possible to get the tx from the event object?

Comment: On my test, I can: `event OnUnfinishedConfirmation(bytes32 key);` and then the event looks like `{ logIndex: 0,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  transactionHash: '0x7509565a2710db91bea97d850058e845eb8ed0ba55e51563843bc3b6ce793446',
  blockHash: '0x5cd1c89bb7a7c5507e7ee14962fecbe7779e9b0d2a3631c8810f370750a222fe',
  blockNumber: 250,
  address: '0xa5df13a15269cb9cfd60ebd3898ee53cc10e94b4',
  type: 'mined',
  event: 'OnUnfinishedConfirmation',
  args: { key: '0x21b8a44a39d69df606804f57e49ed8dbd2c6bf40fd8a1744b4879bfc59562575' } }`

Comment: thanks a lot! I just mark the new transaction as pending and when the event fires, update it to done.

Comment: Nice. If you do not have a corresponding event but still want to wait for the transaction to be mined, you can copy my small helper found here https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6